# Writing wrapper function and handling exceptions correctly in Python

Tags: python, exception, selenium-webdriver

I am writing test scripts using Selenium Webdriver and I have created a simple framework for tests step-by-step execution. My goal was to improve the readability of the code as well as the logic of test scenarios. To do that I wrote some wrappers that group some logic together.

The main ideas are as follows:

1. The application(webpage) that is being tested is defined as a class.
2. Big chunks of code that define a single logical test step are defined as a method of a class. For example a class `WebPage1` and possible method is `LogIn`.
3. Each method (like described in 2) then is wrapped during the execution phase to handle any possible exceptions that might be raised.
4. Additionally, I have a `waitForElement` wrapper function that waits for certain condition on the webpage. If that condition was not met within a pre-defined period of time, it raises a `TimeoutException` which is being handled internally, within the same function.

So to give some idea of what I am talking about, please consider the below example:

```
class Application(object):

    def __init__(self):
        #Some code

    def waitForElement(self, elementName, expectedCondition, searchBy):
        try:
            #conditions
        except TimeoutException:
            #handling

    def logIn(self):
        #code
        self.waitForElement(...)
        #code


app = Application() # initialize an object of class Application

# The below chunk of code attempts to complete the logIn() test step and if ANY 
# exceptions are raised during its execution they will be caught by the BaseException
try:
    app.logIn()
except BaseException as exception:
    #handling
```

So, you can see that the whole step (`logIn()`) in this case is wrapped inside a `try` and there is additional wrapper inside the `waitForElement`.

Now I want to fail the whole execution if `TimeoutException` is raised during `waitForElement` and I want to catch it in the outside wrapper (the `BaseException`). And I still want to handle it locally (inside `waitForElement`).

My first idea was to to raise an additional exception after the initial one is handled. So I did something like that:

```
def waitForElement(self, elementName, expectedCondition, searchBy):
    try:
        #conditions
    except TimeoutException:
        #handling

    raise SystemException
```

So my 2 questions are:

1. Does that approach make sense? It doesn't look very clean to me so maybe I miss something? Another approach perhaps?
2. Ideally, I still want to get the same `TimeoutException` rather than `SystemExit` in the outer exception. If my solution is OK, should I just re-raise the `TimeoutException`?

**P.S.** Hope all that iss clear and make sense. Please let me know in the comments if I should refine my description.

Comment: Any comments why the downvotes and close votes please??